# Converting locale number to number

Tags: javascript

I am able to convert a number to comma separated locale string. Is there a similar function to convert comma separated locale string to a number?

```
var number = 1000000;
number.toLocaleString();
Output: "1,000,000"
```

How to convert 1,000,000 to 1000000 using JavaScript?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```js
var number = 1000000;
console.log('numeric number', number); //1000000

var str = number.toLocaleString();  
console.log('with commas', str);  //1,000,000

var num = str.replace(/\D/g,'');
console.log('string without commas', num);  //1000000  (string)

var num2 = parseInt(num);
console.log('numeric', num2);  //1000000  (numeric)
```

An easy way to convert a string that might contain commas to a number is to find any non-digits within the string and remove it, thus, remaining with only digits.

```
var num = number.toLocaleString().replace(/\D/g,''); //1000000
```

Comment: "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" is thrown !

Comment: @Bharadwaj I updated my answer and included snippet. Check again

Comment: isn't your result still a string? using `parseFloat()` as mentioned in one of the marked duplicates seems to be a good idea.

Comment: you miss decimals in this way

Comment: @quirimmo you are right. I should update my answer

Comment: This doesn't work for locales that use a comma as a decimal and the period as the separator.